Missing faces at ends of voxel chunks
I'm having problems generating faces in a chunk in OpenGL C++. For example, when I generate faces, they are generated correctly but always at the end of the chunks some faces are not generated.

Generate a chunk from noise:
for (int x = 0; x < VoxelSettings::ChunkSize; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < VoxelSettings::ChunkSize; y++) {
            for (int z = 0; z < VoxelSettings::ChunkSize; z++) {
                m_blocks[x][y][z].isSolid = false;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < VoxelSettings::ChunkSize; x++) {
        for (int z = 0; z < VoxelSettings::ChunkSize; z++) {
            auto height = Noise.noise((x + transform.position.x) * 0.005f, (z + transform.position.z) * 0.005f);
            height = (height * 0.5f + 0.5f) * float(VoxelSettings::ChunkSize);

            height = std::floor(height);
            if (height <= 0) {
                height = 1;
            }

            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                m_blocks[x][y][z].isSolid = true;
                m_blocks[x][y][z].transform.position = Vector3((float)x, (float)y, (float)z);
                m_blocks[x][y][z].transform.scale = {0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f};
            }
        }
    }

Add faces to the mesh:

    for (int x = 0; x < VoxelSettings::ChunkSize; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < VoxelSettings::ChunkSize; y++) {
            for (int z = 0; z < VoxelSettings::ChunkSize; z++) {
                auto& block = m_blocks[x][y][z];

                // verifica se o bloco atual existe
                if (block.isSolid) {
                    auto& model = block.transform.getglobalmatrix();

                    // Right face
                    if (checkFace({float(x + 1), float(y), float(z)})) {
                        mesh.addVertice(Vector3(model * Vector4(1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f)), Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
                        mesh.addVertice(Vector3(model * Vector4(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f)), Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
                        mesh.addVertice(Vector3(model * Vector4(1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f)), Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
                        mesh.addVertice(Vector3(model * Vector4(1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f)), Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));

                        u32 baseIndex = mesh.getVerticeCount() - 4;
                        mesh.addtriangle(baseIndex, baseIndex + 1, baseIndex + 2);
                        mesh.addtriangle(baseIndex, baseIndex + 2, baseIndex + 3);
                    }

                    // Left face
                    if (checkFace({float(x - 1), float(y), float(z)})) {
                        mesh.addVertice(Vector3(model * Vector4(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f)), Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f));
                        mesh.addVertice(Vector3(model * Vector4(-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f)), Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f));
                        mesh.addVertice(Vector3(model * Vector4(-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f)), Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f));
                        mesh.addVertice(Vector3(model * Vector4(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f)), Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f));

                        u32 baseIndex = mesh.getVerticeCount() - 4;
                        mesh.addtriangle(baseIndex, baseIndex + 1, baseIndex + 2);
                        mesh.addtriangle(baseIndex, baseIndex + 2, baseIndex + 3);
                    }
                    
                    // Top face
                    if (checkFace({float(x), float(y + 1), float(z)})) {
                        mesh.addVertice(Vector3(model * Vector4(-1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f)), Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
                        mesh.addVertice(Vector3(model * Vector4( 1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f)), Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
                        mesh.addVertice(Vector3(model * Vector4( 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f)), Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
                        mesh.addVertice(Vector3(model * Vector4(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f)), Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));

                        u32 baseIndex = mesh.getVerticeCount() - 4;
                        mesh.addtriangle(baseIndex, baseIndex + 1, baseIndex + 2);
                        mesh.addtriangle(baseIndex, baseIndex + 2, baseIndex + 3);
                    }

                    // Bottom face
                    if (checkFace({float(x), float(y - 1), float(z)})) {
                        mesh.addVertice(Vector3(model * Vector4(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f)), Vector3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f));
                        mesh.addVertice(Vector3(model * Vector4(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f)), Vector3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f));
                        mesh.addVertice(Vector3(model * Vector4( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f)), Vector3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f));
                        mesh.addVertice(Vector3(model * Vector4( 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f)), Vector3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f));

                        u32 baseIndex = mesh.getVerticeCount() - 4;
                        mesh.addtriangle(baseIndex, baseIndex + 1, baseIndex + 2);
                        mesh.addtriangle(baseIndex, baseIndex + 2, baseIndex + 3);
                    }

                    // Front face
                    if (checkFace({float(x), float(y), float(z + 1)})) {
                        mesh.addVertice(Vector3(model * Vector4(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)), Vector3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
                        mesh.addVertice(Vector3(model * Vector4( 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)), Vector3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
                        mesh.addVertice(Vector3(model * Vector4( 1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)), Vector3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
                        mesh.addVertice(Vector3(model * Vector4(-1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)), Vector3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));

                        u32 baseIndex = mesh.getVerticeCount() - 4;
                        mesh.addtriangle(baseIndex, baseIndex + 1, baseIndex + 2);
                        mesh.addtriangle(baseIndex, baseIndex + 2, baseIndex + 3);
                    }

                    // Back face
                    if (checkFace({float(x), float(y), float(z - 1)})) {
                        mesh.addVertice(Vector3(model * Vector4(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f)), Vector3(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
                        mesh.addVertice(Vector3(model * Vector4(-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f)), Vector3(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
                        mesh.addVertice(Vector3(model * Vector4( 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f)), Vector3(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
                        mesh.addVertice(Vector3(model * Vector4( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f)), Vector3(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));

                        u32 baseIndex = mesh.getVerticeCount() - 4;
                        mesh.addtriangle(baseIndex, baseIndex + 1, baseIndex + 2);
                        mesh.addtriangle(baseIndex, baseIndex + 2, baseIndex + 3);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

Check if you can add a face:

const bool ChunkController::checkFace(const Vector3 &position) {
    int x = static_cast<int>(position.x);
    int y = static_cast<int>(position.y);
    int z = static_cast<int>(position.z);

    // verify its inside chunk bounds
    if (x < 0 || x >= VoxelSettings::ChunkSize || y < 0 || y >= VoxelSettings::ChunkSize || z < 0 || z >= VoxelSettings::ChunkSize) {
        return false;
    }

    // verify whether open space or block 
    if (m_blocks[x][y][z].isSolid) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}



Well, looking closely at your screenshot, the problem is occurring on every 16th cell in x and y.
Assuming your VoxelSettings::ChunkSize = 16, then x >= VoxelSettings::ChunkSize is causing the issue as checkFace() will return false where x == 16 (or y == 16). Rather do x > VoxelSettings::ChunkSize (same for y, probably also z). This will solve the problem.

Your checkFace method returns false for all positions that are outside of the current Chunk which means you won't generate a face in that direction.
You can make it just return true for all positions that are outside of the current Chunk, that will already fix the issue you're having but generate some more faces that are not actually visible between chunks.
Or you let checkFace look up if a different chunk has a voxel at that spot which would be ideal but isn't guaranteed to work well if the adjacent chunk doesn't exist (yet)
